# Is LinkedList implementation pointer based in Java?

Tags: java, linked-list

I am trying to learn LinkedList and working on reversing linkedList My code looks like

```
static SinglyLinkedListNode reverse(SinglyLinkedListNode head) {
    if(head == null) return head;
    SinglyLinkedListNode current_node = head;
    SinglyLinkedListNode prevNode = null;

    while(current_node != null) {
        SinglyLinkedListNode next_node = current_node.next;
        current_node.next = prevNode;
        prevNode = current_node;
        current_node = next_node;
    }
    return prevNode;
}
```

My Linked List look like. : 1 > 2 > 3 > 4 > 5

My Question is:
1) Is linked List implementation pointer based? meaning I am doing all operations on current_node not head, so my understanding is head should remain as is and all the changes should be worked upon current_node, but after 1 iteration, I get this while I debug:

[image]

> head.next also changes as I changed current_node.next . Why is that?

Comment: It's reference based, Java doesn't use pointers.  You'll need a doubly-linked list to traverse in reverse.

Comment: As @AdrianM. stated, pointers do not really exist in Java. One thing I can add however is that behind the scenes Java references work essentially through pointers, it is just that pointer functionality is not exposed to the programmer. The statement `current_node.next = prevNode` in a language like C which does use pointers can be translated to `(*current_node).next = &prevNode`. So a reference in Java is basically a pointer but you don't have to use extra pointer notation with it.

Comment: You'll notice that current_node has a reference to the head, which is why it's changing.

Comment: The answer to "is pointer based" is yes but actually no. As other said, pointers do not exist in java but when you want to figure out how a Java LinkedList works It’s okay to pretend it’s pointer based.  "A LinkedList is a doubly-linked list implementation of the List and Deque interfaces" (from [Java 7 SE docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html))